# How to Submit other Modal form on Submit Button click of Current Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal which contains a Submit Button.Apart from this Modal I have another one also which contains Form and other elements like Lables, Text boxes and a Submit button.Now I have a requirement where in a click Submit button of first Modal , it should submit the Form of the Second Modal..Below I am posting my First and Second Modal HTML Prototype ..

```
<div class="modal alert" id="DeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="DeleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="DeleteModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h3>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Are You Sure To Delete !!!</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and Here is the Second One..

```
<div class="modal fade" id="StudentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StudentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<form action="~/GetStudent" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="frmStudent">
<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest me How can this is possible.Thanks..

Comment: Add a class to your `delete button` in your 2nd `modal` and write a `click event` to that `delete button` and inside that `event` close the `modal` where `delete button` exists and `submit` the `form` in the first `modal`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Could you please provide me a Prototype..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `class` to `delete button`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
```

Write a `click event`.

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    $('#DeleteModal').modal('hide');
    $("#frmStudent").submit();
});
```

**Note :**  This is just a basic example. Now if you want to use `ajax` to submit the `form` then there are way different steps to achieve it.